Does Newton's method always converge, assuming no zero derivative and no oscillatory behavior?
For example suppose $f(x) = cos(x) + x$, let initial guess $x_0 = 10000$, solution approximately is -0.73908513321516, at the iteration number 107 I get -0.73908513321516.
Another example is $f(x) = x^3 - 2x + 2$. Avoiding values close to 1 or 0, because it generates oscillatory behaviour, for example suppose initial guess $x_0 = -100000$, at the iteration number 35 I get -1.76929270436664, a solution is precisely at approximately -1.769292354238631.
Another example is $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{2+x} + \cos(x+1) - x^2\cdot \sin(\sqrt{x}/x^2)$, if I avoid negative values during the iteration, I always get a solution.
So my doubt is if Newton's method always work, assuming no zero derivative, no oscillatory behavior, and other restrictions inherent to the function (e.g. if it has square root, then no negative values).
By "no zero derivative" I mean the method never encounters a derivative of 0 during the iterations.  I also assume there's at least one real root for the function. As for oscillatory behavior, that's what this Wikipedia link refers to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Oscillatory_behavior

By "no zero derivative" do you mean the derivative is never $0$ on the whole real line, or just that Newton's method doesn't encounter a derivative of $0$?  And are you assuming a solution exists?

And what exactly do you mean by "no oscillatory behavior"?

Yes, by "no zero derivative" I mean the method never encounters a derivative of 0 during the iterations.  I also assume there's at least one real root for the function. As for oscillatory behavior, that's what this Wikipedia link refers to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Oscillatory_behavior

Unfortunately that wikipedia link is not sufficiently precise about what it means for a sequence to have "oscillatory behavior". Without further clarification from you, one could interpret that as being synonymous with saying that Newton's method "doesn't converge", in which case there's nothing to say: it either converges or it doesn't converge.

Yes, it does. This means the method enters an endless loop, oscillating between only two values [... a, b, a, b, ...], where f(a) ≠ 0 and f(b) ≠ 0. It never converges to a solution.

Let's assume our function $f(x)$ is smooth everywhere and has at least one zero.
Let $N(x) = x - f(x)/f'(x)$, so Newton's method starting at $x_0$ gives you the sequence $x_n$ where $x_{n+1} = N(x_n)$ (assuming you don't run into a denominator of $0$).  For any sequence $x_n$ of distinct points that does not have an accumulation point, we can choose values of $f(x_n)$ and $f'(x_n)$ so that $N(x_n) = x_{n+1}$.  For such a sequence, we must have $|x_n| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.
Alternatively, we could take a sequence that eventually repeats: say $x_0, \ldots, x_{m-1}$ are distinct but $x_m = x_k$ for some $k \le m$, and then
$x_{m+j} = x_{k+j}$ for all $j > 1$.  We could then choose values for $f(x_n)$ and $f'(x_n)$ for $0 \le n \le m$ so that $N(x_n) = x_{n+1}$.
I don't know if you'd call that "oscillatory behavior".
For sequences that don't repeat but do have accumulation points, things are more complicated: if a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ converges to some $y$, and $f'(y) \ne 0$, then $N(x_{n_k}) = x_{n_{k+1}}$ must converge to $N(y)$.  On the other hand, this restriction doesn't apply if $f(y) = f'(y) = 0$.  So e.g. you could have $x_n = -1/n$ for odd $n$  and $x_n = n + 1$ for even $n$.
